# RunningCount/RunningSum Business Objects - how to reset every occurrence of blank

Tags: business-objects

I have a table in Business Objects in which I have created a monthly date spine and I can see how many items a customer bought in a monthly period. What I am trying to do is count the number of months in which no purchases were made and then find the longest gap across the whole date range.

Here is a mock-up in Excel of what I have got so far in Business Objects:

[image]

As you can see I have a running count, but it continues counting every time a blank row is encountered. What I want is that the counting would reset every time a new blank entry is found. I could then find the maximum gap across the date range.

What it should look like is:

[image]

The formula I have at present is:

=RunningSum(IsNull([monthly_purchase]);([monthly_purchase];[date]))

How can I adapt this to get the result I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you need the running count of months? Or is the main objective to determine the maximum number of months in a row with no purchases?

[image]

**Prior Month with Purchases** = Previous([MonthEnd])

**Months Between with No Purchase** =If Not(IsNull([Prior Month with Purchases])) Then MonthsBetween([Prior Month with Purchases];[MonthEnd]) -1 Else 0

**Maximum Gap With No Purchase** =Max([Months Between With No Purchase])

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions. I ended up by transposing the table and having each row represent an individual. I then could determine the start and end date of each customer's interaction across the entire time frame and count the longest gap between purchases which in turn I could then create a flag and filter on. I think there are similarities to your solution however so I shall have a look at it once again.